# Laravel - fill <select> element with old input (edit/update)

Tags: forms, select, laravel

I have to edit a few value's from the database.

with a textfield or area i can just fill the formfield with the old date like this

```
{{ Form::text('hours', Input::old('hours', $vacature->hours), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Aantal uren')) }}
```

where `Input::old('hours', $vacature->hours)` takes care of the old input retrieved from the model.

When i try do to the same with `select` fields, it does not work.

```
 {{ Form::select('employmentType',Input::old('employmentType', $vacature->employmentType), array('vast' => 'Vast dienstverband', 'Freelance' => 'Freelance'), null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

I'm stuck on this for quite a while now. So i hope i can get some help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rearrange the passed arguments:

```
 {{ Form::select('employmentType', array('vast' => 'Vast dienstverband', 'Freelance' => 'Freelance'), Input::old('employmentType', $vacature->employmentType), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Basically you should pass:

- field name
- options (key => value pairs)
- selected value (you set old value if there is one or a default value if there isn't)
- field attributes

or:

```
Form::select('fieldName', $options, $selectedValue, $fieldAttributes)
```

If you don't succeed at first try "slicing" the problem into steps:
see what do you get as an "old" value, see how the select behaves when you pass a static slected value to it etc.

Take care

Comment: Thanks! This solution actually works! So it was just the order of arguments that screwed this up.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that when you use Laravel's form and you bind it to a model, you can just use the `Redirect::back()->withInput();` method and laravel will do the job for you.

here's how you can do this from the Laravel doc :

```
Form::model($user, array('route' => array('user.update', $user->id)))
```

[Doc page.](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#form-model-binding)

Comment: I guess I should bind the models. Right now im not doing it like that. I let the controller just retrieve the data, and then return an array with all the data. Which is a less nice way of doing things i guess :)

Comment: Yup, model binding can be used in forms and routes too, when you bind an object in the route, when you hit the link `users/1` for example laravel will try to fetch the user automatically, so you want have to fetch it manually in your controller.